# Centering two div inside a parent div

Tags: html, css

I am facing this problem

```
#sub-title {
   width: 700px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align:center;
}
#sub-left {
   float: left;
}
#sub-right {
   float: left;
}
.clear-both {
   clear: both;
}

<div id="sub-title">
   <div id="sub-left">
      sub-left
   </div>
   <div id="sub-right">
      sub-right
   </div>
   <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bGF7E/

How do i center sub-left and sub-right? Please ignore the annotated name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a lot of details in your question.

If you don't specify widths of the floating `div`'s, they're only going to be as wide as their contents.

The parent `div` is 700 pixels wide, so to center the two floating `div`'s you'll have to set their widths...

http://jsfiddle.net/bGF7E/6/

http://jsfiddle.net/bGF7E/6/show/

Alternatively, if you'd like content to dictate width of the floating `div`'s, you can simply float the right `div` to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/bGF7E/11/

http://jsfiddle.net/bGF7E/11/show/

Comment: your solution requires that you add 3 width manually. This is not convenient if you want to change one of them, especially when you deal with lots of CSS rules.

Comment: @fflorent, you are incorrect... I only added _two_ widths to the OP's example in my first example and no widths in my second.  And my first solution does not "require" anything other than setting their widths, which can be done in other ways, like with a single `class` rather than setting individual widths on the `id`'s

Answer (score -2):

Is that what you want ?

http://jsfiddle.net/EbskM/

If not, could you bring more precisions about what you want please ?

Comment: You put them inside a `table`... really?

Comment: yes, what is the matter ? 
Table is really a good element to lay out vertically.

Comment: Sure, `table`'s are great for layout if this were 1999.  But it's 2011 and proper layouts are now done with CSS.   It's all beside the point, because the OP specifically asked how to center two `div`'s with CSS and your answer does not use either to achieve the outcome.

Comment: Why are you "clearing floats" in your answer when you're not floating anything?  Also, `div`'s are block level elements so they should never be inside of a `table`.

Comment: 1. I am not so old, I know techniques of 2011. table's are still widely used (take a look at the HTML source of this page). And, even if the OP asked for centering two divs, the main aim was to center two elements you and I finally do (in two different ways).

Comment: 2. because, in order to use table's as I do to center as the OP wanted to do, I needed to get rid of float. And div can be inside a table, I do not know **what is the matter** ?

Comment: **TITLE:**  _"Centering two div inside a parent div"._

Comment: **Why** is there a "clearing" `div` inside your `table`?  Do you even know the purpose of a clearing (`clear:both;`) `div`?

Comment: For anyone reading this who wonders why we no longer use tables for layout:  http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html